# How can I remove Windows Path from Ubuntu Path?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I remove Windows Path from Ubuntu Path ?

~/.bashrc or other file does not contain it.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss = "AppendNtPath"=dword:00000000
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss{....} = "AppendNtPath"=dword:00000000
```

It has no effect.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss{GUID}\Flags
```

Change flags from 7 to 5, has reset my Ubuntu eliminating everything I had.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this in a search, please do *not* modify the registry (as done in the examples in the question) for this.  There is a much easier and safer way to do it (see answers).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent WSL from appending *all* Windows PATH elements to the Linux path, create (or edit) `/etc/wsl.conf` with these contents:

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=false
```

Then exit WSL, do a `wsl --shutdown` from PowerShell or CMD, and restart.

That said, this will make many useful features more difficult to use in WSL, since you will have to call the Windows commands with their full path.  At least consider manually adding back in certain ones in your shell startup, such as:

- `/mnt/c/Windows/System32`
- `/mnt/c/Windows`
- `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/`
- If you have VSCode installed, its path
- If you have PowerShell Core installed, its path

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to *temporary* remove the windows PATHs, you can use this:

```sh
export PATH=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep -v "/mnt/c" | paste -sd ":")
```

It will filter the current `$PATH`, removing all entries starting with `/mnt/c` , keeping everything else, and setting it as your new `$PATH`.

Comment: Good thinking about wanting to sometimes do this temporarily, but I *think* an easier approach for that is simply to `su $USER`.  That will run through a normal PAM-initiated login, which won't get the `/init` added directories from WSL/Windows.

Comment: By the way, if you agree that `su $USER` works and is an easier option, then feel free to add it to your answer.  I don't feel comfortable editing your answer myself since it would change the meaning.  On the other hand, I could certainly add the `su $USER` information to my answer, but you were the one who provided the idea of doing it "temporarily", so I'd like to see you get the credit and upvotes for it.  Let me know if you *don't* want to include it, and if that's the case, I will add it to my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The scenario I imagined (and indeed experienced) was that a single command does not work due to a WSL "override" being in the PATH. Recommending to permanently remove the WSL path could potentially lead to other integrations stopping to work, which might not be clear to the user.

Using `su $USER` would work, but it does not include the parent sessions history, so just running the command that didn't work would be a bit more annoying. The good thing is that you would only need to do `ctrl-d` / `exit` to get back to your regular PATH.

Comment: Good point - The recent history won't be available in Bash since it doesn't add the session history to the history file until it exits, which it doesn't with a `su $USER`.  You could either (1) `history -a; su $USER` (to manually save the history first), or (2) `exec su $USER` (to force the current Bash to terminate, write the history, and start a new Bash that replaces the former), or (3) use the [Fish shell](https://fishshell.com) which keeps the history with just `su $USER`. (1) isn't as "pretty", but (2) has the disadvantage of not being able to `Ctrl+D`/`exit` to "recover" afterwards.

Comment: *"a single command does not work due to a WSL "override" being in the PATH"* - Side note -- Make sure that any Linux directories are *prepended* to the `PATH`.  For instance, `export mydir:$PATH`, rather than `export $PATH:mydir`.  That way the Linux version will always take precedence over the Windows one.   Would that have resolved that particular scenario in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Solved overwriting the path

~/.profile
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

Comment: While it may "work", it's generally a bad idea to hard-code your entire path.  First, while it may work *today*, future versions of the Ubuntu may change the default path, and you could override critical system functionality.  Second, it limits your portability -- If you try to use a different distribution under WSL, or if you tried to move your profile to another system, the system may expect a different PATH.  Best to let the OS manage the default PATH for you.  Feel free to append to it, or modify it, but don't hard-code it entirely.